# What should I do if I want to present 1 variable within years also from different countries at the same time?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, gganimate, rworldmap

Surely im wondering what is the best way to plot the data to make the audieces interested in data visualisation.

For example I have the OECD health data and
choose immunisation part.

Cleaning data and wrangling it into left "year" from 2010 to 2022, "country", "% Measles Immunisation", "% Hep B Immunisation",
"% DPT Immunisation" on children across the country.

In summary, it has 284 obs and 5 variable. make it 6 variable because I mutate country into factor AND it still has NA value.

Do I need select the data to make  more simple? What should I do?

```
# display some data using world map and ggplot containing the DPT immunisation values
# Load world map with country-level detail
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
world <- world %>% 
  select(admin, geometry)

# Assuming 'DPT_immunisation' contains the dataset with no NA value, and only include DPT values
output2 <- DPT_immunisation %>% 
  select(country_fct, year, `% DPT Immunisation of Children`)

# Left join world map data with the DPT immunisation data
plotdata <- inner_join(world, output2, by = c("admin" = "country_fct"))
# save plot data as a file
write.csv(plotdata, "plotdata.csv")

# Creating the ggplot for animation
ggsf <- 
  ggplot (plotdata) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = `% DPT Immunisation of Children`)) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = admin), size = 2, color = "black", check_overlap = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  ggtitle("DPT Immunisation of Children (%) - {closest_state}") +

ggplotly(ggsf) 
# Convert ggplot to interactive plotly graph
interactive_plot <- ggplotly(ggsf)
```

- Why cant the ggsf plotly show?? It said no object ggsf
  and I also tried to used gganimate but it cant show either save as a gif.
- Extra question: how to input ~long, ~lat into our dataset OR change from geometry into ~long, ~lat column??

click for: [data sources](https://stats.oecd.org/viewhtml.aspx?datasetcode=HEALTH_PROC&lang=en)

Comment: “What is the best way” suggests this is a question of opinion which is off-topic for this forum.